# RecycleView not shownig any items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm new to android and kotlin and I'm having trouble making a recycleView for my app
There are 0 errors in my code, but items don't show up in the simulater and the recyclervie is just blank.
I havent connected it to any database and I was just trying to see how my cardviews would look with some placeholders.

I've implemented recycleView and cardView in my gradle file and here's the rest of my code:

each item: `item_project.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/crdProjectItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProjectTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnShare"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Project Title Here"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvProjectDate"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvProjectTitle"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgSyncStatus"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnShare"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgSyncStatus"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="November 3, 2023"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgSyncStatus"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvProjectTitle"
            android:contentDescription="Uploaded"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_sync_24" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnShare"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/btnOptions"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_share_24"
            android:contentDescription="Share"
            />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnOptions"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_more_vert_24"
            android:contentDescription="Options"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

data class: `project.kt`:

```
package com.example.roadsafetycheck


data class Project (
    val title: String,
    val date: String,
    var isSynced: Boolean
    )
```

my adapter: `ProjectAdapter.kt`:

```
package com.example.roadsafetycheck

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ProjectAdapter (
    private val projects : ArrayList<Project>
    ): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProjectAdapter.ProjectViewHolder>() {

    inner class ProjectViewHolder (itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder (itemView) {
        val pTitle : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProjectTitle)
        val pDate : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProjectDate)
        val isSync : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSyncStatus)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProjectViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_project, parent, false)
        return ProjectViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.pTitle.text = projects[position].title
        holder.pDate.text = projects[position].date
        if (projects[position].isSynced){
            holder.isSync.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_sync_24)
        } else {
            holder.isSync.setImageResource(R.drawable.baseline_sync_problem_24)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return projects.size
    }
}
```

main layout: `activity_dashboard.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dashHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:background="@color/blueL" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvProjects"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dashHeader"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally the main activity: `DashboardActivity.kt`

```
package com.example.roadsafetycheck

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.roadsafetycheck.databinding.ActivityDashboardBinding

class DashboardActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityDashboardBinding
    private lateinit var projectsAdapter : ProjectAdapter
    private lateinit var projectsList :ArrayList<Project>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        projectsList = arrayListOf(
            //TODO: connect projectList to database
            //temporary data for demo:

            Project("Kerman-Yazd Road", "1401/10/13", true),
            Project("Kashan-Qom Freeway", "1401/10/30", false),
            Project("Tehran-Karaj Highway", "1401/11/20", true),
            Project("Tehran-Qom Freeway", "1401/12/2", true),
            Project("Resalat Highway", "1401/12/24", true),
            Project("Kerman-BandarAbbas Road", "1402/2/15", true)
        )


        binding.rvProjects.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        projectsAdapter = ProjectAdapter(projectsList)

    }
}
```

I watched multiple tutorials and tried what I've found online so far but nothing seems to work

Comment: You need to set the adapter to the recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not setting your adapter to your `RecyclerView`. Try this after instantiating your adapter:

```kotlin
binding.rvProjects.adapter = projectsAdapter
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this code in the bottom of your dashboard activity:

```
binding.rvProjects.apply{
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        adapter = projectsAdapter
        }
   projectsAdapter = ProjectAdapter(projectsList)
```

if you dont understand or want to see the example check out this [project](https://github.com/DiyorbekJDK/RecycleView-H01)